# VimScript execute search does not work anymore

Tags: vim, neovim

I don't know since when, but my visual selection search function is not working anymore. I broke the problem down to this minimal example.

Assume the following buffer:

```
word
word
word
```

When I run `/word`, I find all results and can jump between them.

When I run `:execute '/word'` this works the same as before.

When I write a short autoload function just doing the same it does not work the same:

`~/.config/nvim/autoload/utils/search.vim`:

```
function! utils#search#visual_selection() abort
    execute '/word'
endfunction
```

Executing `:call utils#search#visual_selection()` makes the cursor land on the first result, but no results are highlighted. Moreover it is using the old search pattern instead of the new one. So if I search first for something non existing like `foo` and then execute this function, pressing `n` give me the error message `Pattern not found: foo`.

What has changed. What is the difference here?

Comment: `~/.config/nvim`? Isn't that neovim?

Comment: Yes. With this path I just wanted to show that I use a correct autoload script so the function call is actually working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually documented behavior of Vim and NeoVim. It's not really related to the use of `:execute` (you can reproduce it with a direct use of `/word`), but with how search (and redo) work in a function.

See [`:help function-search-undo`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#function-search-undo), which states:

> The last used search pattern and the redo command "`.`" will not be changed by the function.  This also   implies that the effect of `:nohlsearch` is undone when the function returns.

You can work around that by explicitly setting the [search pattern register](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#quote_%2F), which you can do with a `let` command.

```
function! utils#search#visual_selection()
    let @/ = 'word'
    execute "normal /\<cr>"
endfunction
```

The second command executes a simple `/` from normal mode, that is enough to search for word, since it will look for the last search pattern which is now set to what you wanted.

After the function is finished, the search pattern will keep its value, which means highlighting through `'hlsearch'` will work, and so will the `n` command to find the next match.

---

A restriction from the approach above is that you can't really set search direction for repeats with `n`. Even though there is [`v:searchforward`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#v%3Asearchforward), which can be set, that variable is also reset after a function as part of the [`:help function-search-undo`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#function-search-undo) effects. There doesn't seem to be anything you can do about that one...

If the purpose of this function is for use in a key mapping, you might consider a completely different approach, using `nnoremap <expr>` and having the function return the normal mode command for the search as a string, that way the actual search happens outside of the function and the restrictions from `function-search-undo` won't apply.

For example:

```
function! utils#search#visual_selection(searchforward)
    let pattern = 'word'
    if a:searchforward
        let dir = '?'
    else
        let dir = '/'
    endif
    return dir.pattern."\<cr>"
endfunction
```

And then:

```
" Mappings for next-word and previous-word
nnoremap <expr> <leader>nw utils#search#visual_selection(1)
nnoremap <expr> <leader>pw utils#search#visual_selection(0)
```

This avoids the issue with [`:help function-search-undo`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#function-search-undo) altogether, so consider something like this approach, if possible in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! It helped me a lot! Unfortuanly the jump to the next result does not work the first time. Instead it seam to jump to jump to the first column of the next line with an entry (entries in same line become ignored). Afterwards I can use `n` and `N` as usual because of the register. How can I make this become more neat?

Comment: @weilbith Fixed now. It turns out a simple `/` is search from Ex mode and that will happen linewise. Fixed to use `/` "return" from normal mode. Unfortunately that's a fairly long command, but it should work as expected.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for you work! Last question: I observed that if I use it with `?` for backward search, on execution it jumps back in the buffer. But using `n` afterwards goes forward again. How can I make sure it recognize the direction. I guess as before what happens in the function gets lost, so `n` refers to the default direction forwards. Can I do something persistent like with the search register here as well?

Comment: There is [`v:searchforward`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#v%3Asearchforward) which you can set, but unfortunately it's also reset after a function and there doesn't seem to be anything you can do about that one... If you're using this for a key mapping, you might consider a completely different approach, using `nnoremap <expr>` and having the function return the normal mode command for the search as a string, that way the search happens outside of the function and the restrictions from `function-search-undo` won't apply.